# xamarin c# UIViewController with scrolling text

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS app with xamarin studio, with only code, and without Storyboard or any designer, only with c# code.

I need to put a UILabel (or UITextView) with a long text, longer then the UIViewController.
For example, this is my UILabel with the long text:

```
   string textrStr = "";
        var descStrLabel = new UITextView(new CGRect(0, 340, w, 1050));
        descStrLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        descStrLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10.0f);
        descStrLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified;
        descStrLabel.TextColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        textrStr += @"È universalmente riconosciuto che un lettore che osserva il layout di una pagina viene distratto dal contenuto testuale se questo è leggibile. Lo scopo dell’utilizzo del Lorem Ipsum è che offre una normale distribuzione delle lettere (al contrario di quanto avviene se si utilizzano brevi frasi ripetute, ad esempio “testo qui”), apparendo come un normale blocco di testo leggibile. Molti software di impaginazione e di web design utilizzano Lorem Ipsum come testo modello. Molte versioni del testo sono state prodotte negli anni, a volte casualmente, a volte di proposito (ad esempio inserendo passaggi ironici).";

        descStrLabel.Text = textrStr;
        descStrLabel.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        descStrLabel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
```

This text will be longer then the device screen, so i need to scroll it.
I tried several solutions, but nothing is working.

Comment: What have you tried?  First Recommendation would be to insert the label into a UIScrollView.  Usage documentation is located here, https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/use_a_scrollview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the height you have set for the UITextView, 1050. This is higher than the screen height and if it is high enough to hold all of the text, then no scrolling is needed. But since it is higher than the screen, you will not see all of the text as most of the UITextView is itself off screen. Set the height to be the amount of height you want the text view to take up on screen, which I would assume to be `screen (or view) height - 340` since 340 is where you have the top of the UITextView, and not the height it needs to be to hold all of the text. A UITextView Will be scrollable only if it is too small to hold all of the text.

I can't see from your code whether you have this UITextView in the main View of a view controller or whether it is in a subview. If in the main View, try:

```
var descStrLabel = new UITextView(new CGRect(0, 340, w, View.Bounds.Height - 340));
```

If in a subview, replace `View.Bounds.Height - 340` with `containerView.Bounds.Height - 340`

Also if you need to support landscape orientation, I would recommend adding a FlexibleHeight flag:

```
descStrLabel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
```

Without that flag, when you rotate to landscape you will no longer be able to scroll all the way to the bottom as the height of the UITextView is now too high to be fully on screen.

I hope this helps!